# Webdriver.chrome not opening chrome

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, chrome-web-driver

I'm working on an automation script and I'm trying to open a url in chrome, I have installed and imported selenium and downloaded the chrome driver and moved it to /usr/local/bin.

But when I try and run the script, the console is blank and then about a second later it displays 'Process finished with exit code 0' as if nothing happened. Below is my current code:

```
from selenium import webdriver


class Script():
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')

    def login(self):
        self.driver.get('https://facebook.com')
```

Answer (score 0):

The path is wrong here. It should be like below
`webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'/usr/local/bin/chromedriver.exe')`
Need to add .exe extension in the executable_path.
Also, make sure you are using correct Version of chrome driver for Google Chrome.

Comment: I tried that previously but the same output happened in the console. I have tried two different versions of the chrome driver, I am using chrome version 80 and have tried a 80 version and 79 but both don't seem to work.

Comment: The simple script should be,
`from selenium import webdriver`
`import time`
`driver=  webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='the path where chrome driver is placed')`
`driver.get("https://www.facebook.com")`
`time.sleep(2) #sleep time to see the brower`

Since you are using classes and functions, make sure to call them as expected.

Comment: I am calling them and have tried numerous different methods now and none of them are working for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
from config import keys
from selenium import webdriver

def order():

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
    driver.get('https://facebook.com')
    print("here")

if __name__== '__main__':
    order()
```

An exit code 0 means that ran without error. If an error occurs it would provide a non-zero argument. I would add a

```
from selenium import webdriver


class Script():
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')

    def login(self):
        self.driver.get('https://facebook.com')
        print ('Opened facebook')
```

This should return with "Opened facebook" then 'Process finished with exit code 0'. I built something similar that will log a user into Facebook.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

class Script():
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')

    def login(self):
        self.driver.get('https://facebook.com')
        print ('Opened facebook')       
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.driver.get(k['product_url'])
        print ('Opened facebook')
        username_box = self.driver.find_element_by_id('email')
        username_box.send_keys('EMAIL ADDRESS')
        print ('Email Id entered')
        password_box = self.driver.find_element_by_id('pass')
        password_box.send_keys('password')
        print ('Password entered')
        login_box = self.driver.find_element_by_id('loginbutton')
        login_box.click()
        print('Logged In')
```

Comment: Thanks very much, but, by adding the print statement and running the program, the same thing happens as before, no print statement is shown in the console for some reason.

Comment: Unfortunately none of the methods work for some reason, I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: I added the (executable_path='/usr/local/bin/chromedriver') to my answer...

Answer (score 0):

You are on [linux](/questions/tagged/linux) system. You don't need the *raw* i.e. `r` switch. Your effective line of code will be:

```
self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
```